# React native, load component on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native project in which I want to render a component on a button click .. the buttons are displayed as a bottom bar, in which every button should render a component.

I tried to set the state like this :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedPage : '' }
}
```

And in my buttons I tried to set the state of each button to a value :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({ selectedPage : 'completed }), this._handleCaseView() }> Completed </TouchableOpacity>
```

Then I tried to change the value of a variable defined in the `render()` method with default value of an imported component `let caseView = <PendingCases />`

my _handleCaseView()

```
_handleCaseView = () => {
    switch (this.state.selectedPage) {
      case "completed":
        this.caseView = <Text> Completed </Text>;
        break;
      case "delayed":
        this.caseView = <Text> Delayed </Text>;
        break;
      case "all":
        this.caseView = <PendingCases />;
        break;
      case "approved":
        this.caseView = <Text> Approved </Text>;
        break;
      case "set-by-doctor":
        this.caseView = <Text> SET BY DOCTOR </Text>;
        break;
      default:
        this.caseView = <PendingCases />;
    }
  }
```

Then in my render method `<View> { this.caseView } </View>`

The problem is that the value isn't getting set, is there a simpler approach ?

--UPDATE--

here is my `render()` function

```
return (

      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={200}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Right}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
      >

          <View style={{ flex : 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'rgb(250, 250, 250)' }}>

          <HeaderWText header="Cases" />

          <View style={ styles.pageBody }>

          <View> { this.renderCaseView(this.state.selectedPage) } </View>

          </View>

        </View>

        <View style={{ height: 70, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)', borderTopWidth: 1, flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({ selectedPage : "completed" }) } style={{ flex : 1, padding: 5 }}>
            <View style={{ flex : 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Image style={{ width : 35, height: 35}} source={require('./images/completed.png')} />
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12}}>Completed</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({ selectedPage : "delayed"}) } style={{ flex : 1, padding: 5 }}>
            <View style={{ flex : 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Image style={{ width : 35, height: 35}} source={require('./images/delayed.png')} />
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12}}>Delayed</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>

    )
```

my `constructor()` and `renderCaseView()`

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedPage : 'completed' }
  }

  renderCaseView = (param) => {
    switch (param) {
      case "completed":
        return <PendingCases />;
        break;
      case "delayed":
        return <Text> Delayed </Text>;
        break;
      case "all":
        return <PendingCases />;
        break;
      case "approved":
        return <Text> Approved </Text>;
        break;
      case "set-by-doctor":
        return <Text> SET BY DOCTOR </Text>;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't have to use setState callback - you can use this kind of logic inside render 'body' (before `return`) or call function from render (param/switch/return <Component>)

Comment: Did you put any logs inside the `_handleCaseView` to make sure that is changing?  Maybe is a good idea to use `this._handleCaseView() ` inside your render method

Comment: @xadm i'm sorry could you explain it a little more ? i'm not sure i quite got your answer

Comment: Just call `{this._handleCaseView()}` inside your render method

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `onPress` event to return a `single function`, right now you're returning `multiple functions` to it.

```
onPress={ () => {
  this.setState({ selectedPage : 'completed' }); // Your Updater function
  this._handleCaseView()
}
```

Another thing to note is , since `handleCaseView` is dependant on `state` and you're calling them `async`, therefore you need to call it once the **state has finished updating** in the `setState` *callback parameter*.

```
onPress={ () => {
      this.setState({ selectedPage : 'completed' }, () => this.handleCaseView());
}
```

Comment: Few things completed must be enclosed in single quotes quote missing and switch case will be always same because onPress is always setting completed so the switch case always goes to this <Text> Completed </Text>

Comment: Thanks, updated, the usage for the updater function would be for the author to decide :).

Answer (score 1):

There're a few methods, you can extend render method with logic like this:

```
render() {
  const ChoosenView = this.state.selectedPage ? <Completed /> : <Delayed />
  // or more complicated vanilla js logic
  // call parametrized method, etc
  // to prepare 'visual parts'

  return (
    <Layout>
      {ChoosenView}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

you can refactor `_handleCaseView` to

```
renderCaseView = (param) => {
    // you can use Map/object definitions instead of switch
    switch (param) {
      case "completed":
        return <Text> Completed </Text>;
      case "delayed":
        return <Text> Delayed </Text>;
      case "all":
        return <PendingCases />;
      case "approved":
        return <Text> Approved </Text>;
      case "set-by-doctor":
        return <Text> SET BY DOCTOR </Text>;
      default:
        return <PendingCases />;
    }
}
```

and use it in render directly

```
{this.renderCaseView(this.state.selectedPage)}
```

Comment: the second method throws me an error of `Cannot add child that doesn't have a YogaNode ...`

Comment: i changed the `TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=> this.renderCaseView('completed') }` and in the render i called `{ this.renderCaseView() }` .. i was trying to find another solution ..

Comment: grrr...  render (returning components) in handler? WHY? in event handler you have only to setState, render will be fired/forced with new, updated state value - it's simple 'flow'

Comment: i updated the question .. please could you take a look ?

Comment: it can be sth RN related - try 1st method with `const ChoosenView = this.renderCaseView(this.state.selectedPage)`, console.log it's value (and this.state.selectedPage?) - just debug it.

Comment: but i actually have 5 buttons, your first method is using `if () {} else {}` shorthand right ?

Comment: grrr, did you read my last comment?? there is a ChoosenView calling renderCaseView, not if conditions